# postgres query to count data which contains ' or : or " and space

Tags: postgresql

the column "A", note the column is not in json data type , just normal varchar type:

```
{
  "Id": "f0daac20-934e-4e7e-bae4-bd323bd61dec",
  "status": "PLANNING",
}
```

my query like this return nothing / 0 count:

```
SELECT * FROM table1.test where lower(A) LIKE '%"state": "PLANNING"%'

SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table1.test where lower(A) LIKE '%"state": "PLANNING"%'
```

i guess the space after semicolon causing the problem, not sure about it.

Comment: It is `status`, not `state`.

Comment: Note that `:` is called _colon_. The character `;` is the semicolon

Comment: @muistooshort you are right, i just realize and removed the lower. it works. thanks

Comment: You should seriously consider changing that column to `jsonb` if you store json values in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just cast it to JSON and use json functions?

```
select count(*)
from the_table
where the_column::jsonb @> '{"status": "PLANNING"}'
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d1fd26dd89f3047be48c3057660d5582)

Comment: @user12158726: works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d1fd26dd89f3047be48c3057660d5582 - is it `state` or `status`?